# How to delete worker task templates in AWS Augmented AI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've created the worker task template for test in AWS Augmented AI.
However, I don't know how to delete those template.

Please tell me how to do it.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZkiz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently delete HumanTaskUis. That may be a capability added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can [now](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-augmented-ai-launches-delete-human-task-ui-capability/) delete a HumanTaskUi

[Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.delete_human_task_ui)

```
client = boto3.client('sagemaker', REGION)

response = client.delete_human_task_ui(HumanTaskUiName=HUMAN_TASK_UI_NAME)
```

[AWS CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sagemaker/delete-human-task-ui.html)